# Problem with graphics card (Geforce gt 240)

Tags: graphics

Im having problem running Ubuntu 15.04. After startup I see artifacts on the screen like triangles and shroud. Then few minutes later the screen goes black.

With Ubuntu 14.04 i was unable to run it at all. Also it failed with Mint linux.

All works fine with Windows so I guess its not hardware issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Re) install the NVIDIA drivers, but first uninstall all NVIDIA software you had installed before.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the "**e**" key.
Add the **nouveau.modeset=0** parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press **F10** to boot.

Install the stable NVIDIA drivers from the Ubuntu repositories :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo reboot
```

In case you are using a notebook with hybrid graphics solution install Optimus support as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll certainly approve it if it'll work. The problem is that ... I don't know if that'll work when running up Ubuntu from CD, because as for now I'm unable to even install it, and If I do.. I'm having some other problems - like the fact I dont know if my current system will remain after installation (I'm having problem that Ubuntu installer can't even see all my partitions). Well, just saying, that's problably a matter for another question.

Comment: @ŁukaszMichalczyk : If you choose "Something else" from ubuntu installer and select the ubuntu partition you will NOT loose your Windows installation ! :)

Comment: Actually the problem is even that i cant install the system due to this issue... the installer goes black after a while.  I will have to figure out how to install Ubuntu from command line.

Comment: @ŁukaszMichalczyk : When booting from Ubuntu install media - did you highlight "Try Ubuntu without installing" - press the "e" key - add the "nouveau.modeset=0" parameter to the end of the linux line ... and then press F10 to boot ?

Comment: The problem is I cant see grub while booting from dvd. Is there a way to get into it?

Comment: It allows me to choose if I want to continue with the Live mode or to start installation. The weird thing is that the artifacts dont appear here. They happen after the Live mode fire up.

Comment: @ŁukaszMichalczyk : okay - then select : start the installation and after having installed the base system, reboot and follow the instructions given in my answer. :)

Comment: You didnt get me correct :) The thing is I cant see artifacts but the screen goes black the same way it does in live mode :)

Comment: @ŁukaszMichalczyk : Maybe something went wrong when creating the install media - so I suggest that you create a new DVD or USB installation media. :)

Comment: I think the media is fine - it's not my first attempt to run Ubuntu on this machine, I've had same problem with different media before, only that now I'm stubborn on this and actually asking for help.

Comment: It works, check out my answer below, there are few points we missed :)

Answer (score 0):

So basically what @cl-netbox said is correct, thus the answer is accepted. But in many cases there may be more things to consider. 
First at all is the fact that I was unable to start installation at all. After running from the LiveCD - no matter if I chose to start installation or to try the Ubuntu - I got the black screen after a while so I was unable to install Ubuntu this way.

The solution to this was to get to the pre-launch menu. To do so you need to press any key when the Ubuntu starts booting, while on the purple screen with a keyboard icon.

When the menu appeared I had to highlight the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option and press **F6** and the **"ESC"**. This way the boot options line showed on the bottom of the screen - now I needed to delete the ending three "---" and append the "noveau.modeset=0" text to it, and press enter in order to start the Ubuntu form LiveCD. This allowed me to install Ubuntu later by clicking the "install Ubuntu" icon on the desktop.

After the installation was done I had to reboot and do the steps described by @cl-netbox but a little different. I've needed to start the now installed Ubuntu system with the "nouveau.modeset=0" still intact, because otherwise the system would hang while trying to uninstall existing drivers. So I've highlihted the **Ubuntu** entry and pressed **"e"** and appended the "nouveau.modeset=0" to the end of the line starting with "linux" word, pressed **F10** and the system has boot.

Then I've issued the:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

..commands in the terminal. At this point the console told me that no drivers were installed (this may probably vary between Ubuntu versions) so I've immediately issued commands to install the new drivers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo reboot
```

After reboot the system was all fine and working well.

---

As a side note I would like to say that I think the problem with nouveau drivers is that they probably overheat the GPU. Before I've fixed the problem the situation looked like following: 
Every time , after the screen went black, during the reboot - I could hear the GPU fan working at maximum speed for a few seconds. 
This could be verified by taking actuall measurements, but if this really the case - the issue is not only a problem on itself but also a threat for the underlying hardware.